# Can I use segue to change image on other view controller on Xcode? objective c

Tags: ios, xcode, image, segue

I am trying to use a button to change the image on **second viewController** , but I don't know how? Do I need to do something or just pass it in prepare for segue like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"the_segue"]){
        imageView.image=@"photo.jpg"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can get second vc via `segue.destinationViewController` property and change needed property, for example: `viewController.image=@"photo.jpg"`

Comment: You should pass the `UIImage` instead of directly setting it to the `UIImageView` and in the `viewDidLoad` of  your second view controller set the `UIImage` to `UIImageView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"the_segue"]){
        secondViewController *VC2 = (secondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController
        VC2.imageView.image=@"photo.jpg"
    }
}
```

In your SecondViewController look like

```
@interface secondViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,readwrite) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```